# Comparing lists of different type with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a lists the loads from an XML.

The XML looks like this:

```
<TablesToSynchronize>
<Table name="dbo.Table1" />
<Table name="dbo.Table2" />
<Table name="dbo.Table3" />
<Table name="dbo.Table4" />
</TablesToSynchronize>
```

I want to compare a list of `XElement` with a list of `string`, but I can't get it together.

```
    private static readonly XDocument TableSettings = XDocument.Load(GetAssemblyDirectory() + @"\Tables.xml");
    private static List<XElement> TablesToSync = new List<XElement>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        {
            var test = TableSettings.Descendants("Table").Select(x => x.Attribute("name").Value.ToString());

            test = test.Where(args.ToList().Contains).ToList();


            var test2 = (from x in TableSettings.Descendants("Table")
                where x.Attribute("name").Value == "dbo.Table1"
                select x).ToList();

            //TablesToSync = ??
        }
    }
```

var `test2` is working fine, but it returns only the `XElement` with "Table1". I want to loop args and check if any item there matches `XElement` attribute `("name").Value`.

What am I missing here?

args contains dbo.Table1, dbo.Table2, dbo.Table3

UPDATE: test2 gives me a list of `XElement` containing dbo.Table1. test gives me an empty list of `string`.

The output should be a `List<XElement>`

Comment: sorry, it should be dbo.Table everywhere. Will update

Comment: you can use [join clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb311040.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) something like `from x in TableSettings.Descendants("Table") from y in args
                join x.Attribute("name").Value equals y
                select x`

Comment: maybe this will work

test = test.where(t => args.ToList().Contains(t)).ToList()

Comment: What is your expected output? A list of `XElement` or a list of `string`? What is wrong with the contents of `test` variable? 
Please include these details in your question.

Comment: @Mathew The expected output is a list of XElement. TablesToSync =. Will update

Comment: `Where(t=>args.Contains(t))` is enough to check all arguments. No need to iterate at all

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That gives me a empty list...Even if I use Contains("dbo.Table1")

Comment: @krillezzz so check values in `args` variable. Possible it simple empty if you don't pass command line parameters when running

Comment: @Grundy It's not empty. Double checked

Comment: @krillezzz do use check concrete values? it realy `dbo.Table1` and others?

Comment: Yes, the values sent into args is sent like -> program.exe dbo.table1 dbo.table2

Comment: @krillezzz contains methink is case sensitive

Comment: @Grundy Thats the solution right there. I missed a simple case sensetive char....thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will return two elements:

```
args = new[] { "dbo.Table1", "dbo.Table3" };
var test = (from elt in TableSettings.Descendants("Table")
            where args.Contains(elt.Attribute("name").Value)
            select elt).ToList();
Debug.Assert(test.Count==2);
```

or

```
args = new[] { "dbo.Table1", "dbo.Table3" };
var test = (from elt in TableSettings.Descendants("Table")
            where args.Contains((string)elt.Attribute("name"))
            select elt).ToList();
```

or the equivalent as a method chain:

```
var test = TableSettings.Descendants("Table")
                        .Where(elt => args.Contains(elt.Attribute("name").Value))
                        .ToList();
```

An XAttribute explicitly convertible to one of the basic .NET types so you have to use the `(string)` cast. Otherwise .NET will compare the XAttribute instance against a string value.

If you have a lot of arguments and worry that `Contains` is slow, you can convert the string array to a dictionary:

```
var argsDict = args.ToDictionary(x => x);
var test = TableSettings.Descendants("Table").                    
                Where(elt => argsDict.ContainsKey(elt.Attribute("name").Value))
                .ToList();
```

A quick test of 10000000 iterations returns these not-very-meaningful results:

- Where      : 33466320 ticks
- Join       : 32560386 ticks
- Dictionary : 22998512 ticks
- HashSet    : 25979814 ticks

The difference between `Where` and `Join` is negligible (~2%) and can easily be attributed to noise. A dictionary or hashset though is significantly faster (~30%).

In fact, the differences between the equivalent methods fluctuate a lot and are essentially meaningless.

This isn't surprising as a dictionary/hashset is essentially acting as an index would act in SQL. In fact, SQL Server will use hash joins when one of the two tables in a join is (relatively) small.

A dictionary may perform better  if you need to access more than the key from the arguments, as you can lookup and retrieve the matching value in a single operation. This is similar to using a covering index in SQL:

```
MyOtherClass v=null;
var test = from elt in TableSettings.Descendants("Table")
           let value = elt.Attribute("name").Value
           where argsDict.TryGetValue(value, out v)
           select new {elt, v};
```

This is rather ugly though in C# 5. This is where the (now scrapped) declaration expressions in C# 6 would have helped:

```
var test = from elt in TableSettings.Descendants("Table")
           let value = elt.Attribute("name").Value
           where argsDict.TryGetValue(value, out var v)
           select new {elt, v};
```

Comment: in this case better use _HashSet_ instead simple array

Comment: @Grundy or a Dictionary.

Comment: The differences in performance are meaningless. While `Join` obscures what the statement tries to achieve, the difference between `HashSet` or `Dictionary` *for the keys only( is down to personal taste

Comment: @Grundy a dictionary is preferable if you need more than the key from the arguments, similar to using a covering index in SQL. Avoids an extra lookup

Comment: in this case you use only keys from Dictionary, so [Jon Skeet suggest use HashSet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728500/hashsett-versus-dictionaryk-v-w-r-t-searching-time-to-find-if-an-item-exist) :-)

Comment: @Grundy the difference in speed is meaningless. Jon Skeet's answer has to do with fitness for purpose, not speed, That's why a `Where` is better than a `Join`. While nitpicking, a join is an alternative expression for an intersection set operation. If this weren't XML, you could simply create a HashSet for each collection's keys and call `Intersect` to quickly find the matches.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to achieve what you want one using the `Where` and second using the `JOIN`

You can apply the join to get your result as

```
  var mytest = TableSettings.Descendants("Table").Join(arggs, x => x.Attribute("name").Value, y => y, (x, y) => new { Element = x });
```

and you can apply the `Where` as

```
   TablesToSync = TableSettings.Descendants("Table").Where(x => arggs.Contains(x.Attribute("name").Value)).ToList();
```

If your data is small then it should not give lot of performance improvements to which one you decide to use. But if you have large data read comments and more stuff about this you should decide for yourself which approach you want to follow.

Comment: This is just a `value in list` query. Joining in rather excessive. Just a `Where(t=>args.Contains(t))` will return the matching elements. Not to mention, you are using `Join` here as both a `Where` and a `Select` statement. This is a bit confusing and in this example, just not needed. The `where` part already returns the desired type

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos why you think _joining in rather excessive_?

Comment: @Grundy the OP here asks simply to filter a collection, *not* join two separate collections.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Now when you mentioned I read it here [JOIN vs WHERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where) And it is mentioned that join actually performs better in case of large data. Because where generates Cartesian product and join takes only matching values.

Comment: in this case filter and join is same, because filter depends on second collection, methinks it more classic _inner join_ rather filter

Comment: @CoderofCode The link is *completely* irrelevant. LINQ **isn't SQL**. The OP asks about LINQ to XML. Even if it was LINQ to SQL or EF, the equivalent SQL query would be `WHERE x in ('a','b','c')` not a join between two tables. The best performing option here would be the equivalent of an XPath query on the attribute value

Comment: @Grundy this isn't a database, it's LINQ to XML. Even in SQL you'd use `WHERE x in Y`, not create a temporary table just to join with the arguments. There's no inner or outer table here. Just a single table whose values need to be filtered

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, join in linq is simple intersection of some collections, concrete implementation depends on used provider

Comment: I don't see why it's *rather excessive* to use `Join`. it's the correct approach to use here (if you want to use Linq). `Where(x=>foo.Contains(x))` is harder to read, slower, and, depending on your use case, may require an additional `Select`.