# Use .Contains() to match on a property of a property of <T> in LINQ query

Tags: vb.net, linq

Looking for help on how to perform a LINQ query using the `.Contains()` method of a `List(Of T)` to get back elements that are not contained in a second `List(Of T)` based on a property of a property of `T` in the first `List(Of T)`.

Here is some sample code that I wrote up, this scenario is ficticious, but the concept is still there.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        ' Get all Files in a directory that contain `.mp` in the name
        Dim AllFiles As List(Of IO.FileInfo) = New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Test\Path").GetFiles("*.mp*").ToList
        Dim ValidFiles As New List(Of fileStruct)

        ' Get all Files that actually have an extension of `.mp3`
        AllFiles.ForEach(Sub(x) If x.Extension.Contains("mp3") Then ValidFiles.Add(New fileStruct(prop1:=x.Name, path:=x.FullName)))

        ' Attempting the get all files that are not listed in the Valid files list
        Dim InvalidFiles As IO.FileInfo() = From file As IO.FileInfo In AllFiles Where Not ValidFiles.Contains(Function(x As fileStruct) x.fleInfo.FullName = file.FullName) Select file
        ' Errors on the `.Contains()` method because I have no idea what I'm doing and I am basically guessing at this point

        'Here is the same but instead using the `.Any()` Method
        Dim InvalidFiles As IO.FileInfo() = From file As IO.FileInfo In AllFiles Where Not ValidFiles.Any(Function(x As fileStruct) x.fleInfo.FullName = file.FullName) Select file
        ' This doesn't error out, but all files are returned
    End Sub

    Public Structure fileStruct
        Private _filePath As String
        Private _property1 As String

        Public ReadOnly Property property1 As String
            Get
                Return _property1
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property fleInfo As IO.FileInfo
            Get
                Return New IO.FileInfo(_filePath)
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Sub New(ByVal prop1 As String, ByVal path As String)
            _property1 = prop1
            _filePath = path
        End Sub
    End Structure
End Module
```

Comment: If you're trying to get the difference between two lists don't use `Contains()`, use `Except()`.

Comment: @CraigW - The `.Except()` method is looking for a second collection of the same type as the first. In my case, the collections are not of the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more or less direct implementation of the MP3 files list in the question.  I did use a `FileItem` class instead of a structure.  The good part is afterwards:

```
' note: EnumerateFiles
Dim AllFiles As List(Of IO.FileInfo) = New IO.DirectoryInfo("M:\Music").
    EnumerateFiles("*.mp*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList()

Dim goofyFilter As String() = {"g", "h", "s", "a"}

' filter All files to those starting with the above (lots of
' Aerosmith, Steely Dan and Heart)
Dim ValidFiles As List(Of FileItem) = AllFiles.
                Where(Function(w) goofyFilter.Contains((w.Name.ToLower)(0))).
                Select(Function(s) New FileItem(s.FullName)).ToList()

Dim invalid As List(Of FileInfo)

invalid = AllFiles.Where(Function(w) Not ValidFiles.
                        Any(Function(a) w.FullName = a.FilePath)).ToList()
```

This is much the same as Sam's answer except with your file/mp3 usage.  AllFiles has 809 items, ValidFiles has 274.  The resulting invalid list is 535.

---

Now, lets **speed it up 50-60x**:

Same starting code for `AllFiles` and `ValidFiles`:

```
Dim FileItemValid = Function(s As String)
                        Dim valid As Boolean = False
                        For Each fi As FileItem In ValidFiles
                            If fi.FilePath = s Then
                                valid = True
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next
                        Return valid
                    End Function

invalid = AllFiles.Where(Function(w) FileItemValid(w.FullName) = False).ToList()
```

With a `Stopwatch`, the results are:

> ```
>     Where/Any count: 535, time: 572ms  
> FileItemValid count: 535, time: 9ms
> ```

You get similar results with a plain old For/Each loop that calls an `IsValid` function.

---

If you do not need other `FileInfo`, you could create your `AllFiles` as a list of the same structure as you are receiving so you can do property vs property compares, use `Except` and `Contains`:

```
AllFiles2 = Directory.EnumerateFiles("M:\Music", "*.mp3", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).
            Select(Function(s) New FileItem(s)).ToList()
```

Now you can use `Contains` with middling results:

```
invalid2 = AllFiles2.Where(Function(w) Not ValidFiles.Contains(w)).ToList()
```

This also allows you to use `Except` which is simpler and faster:

```
invalid2 = AllFiles2.Except(ValidFiles).ToList()
```

> ```
>  Where/Contains count: 535, time: 74ms  
>          Except count: 535, time: 3ms
> ```

Even if you need other items from FileInfo, you can easily fetch them given the filename

Comment: But still have multiple iterations of AllFiles (one time for the valid files, one time for the invalid files)

Comment: No.  AllFiles is iterated once testing if each is in ValidFiles.  That results in at least a partial iteration of ValidFiles, but *invalid(files)* is the result.  The IL code for a For/Each loop and the Where and anon lambda is basically identical

Comment: Plus One for Steely Dan.  Definitely belongs in the Valid Files list.

Comment: Also, if you want to really speed things up, use a HashSet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728500/hashsett-versus-dictionaryk-v-w-r-t-searching-time-to-find-if-an-item-exist

Comment: Actually 3-4ms is about as fast as it seems to go.  A Hashset for ValidFiles speeds up Where/Contains from 74 to 4ms, but it is slower than some of the others (by only a very little).  The problem for the OP may be using a hashset with them since the come from elsewhere.

Comment: I used the Lamda in a variable option in my project, however to make the results of my COM object match on the path I had to use `.Normalize()` and `.Equals()` on the paths: `If fi.LocalPackage.FullName.Normalize.Equals(inFle.FullName.Normalize, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then`

Comment: The string handling makes sense considering COM (we of course cant tell that from the question).

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, .Except() is a better approach but here is an answer to your question:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 3, 4, 5 };

List<int> list3 = list1.Where(list1value => !list2.Contains(list1value)).ToList();  // 1, 2
```

Based on comments here as an example using different types.  This query use .Any()

```
List<Product> list1 = new List<Produc> { ... };

List<Vendor> list2 = new List<Vendor> { ... };

List<Product> list3 = list1.Where(product => !list2.Any(vendor => product.VendorID == vendor.ID)).ToList();  


// list3 will contain products with a vendorID that does not match the ID of any vendor in list2.
```

Comment: Using your example, what I need to match on is `list1value.someProperty.value` to `list2`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Except as CraigW suggested. You have to do some projections (select) to get it done.

```
Dim InvalidFiles as IO.FileInfo() = AllFiles.Select(Function(p) p.FullName).Except(ValidFiles.Select(Function(x) x.fleInfo.FullName)).Select(Function(fullName) New IO.FileInfo(fullName)).ToArray()
```

Note: This code is not really efficient and also not very readable but works.

But i would go for something like this:

```
Dim AllFiles As List(Of IO.FileInfo) = New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\MyFiles").GetFiles("*.mp*").ToList
Dim ValidFiles As New List(Of fileStruct)
Dim InvalidFiles as New List(Of FileInfo)

For Each fileInfo As FileInfo In AllFiles
    If fileInfo.Extension.Contains("mp3") Then 
        ValidFiles.Add(New fileStruct(prop1:=fileInfo.Name, path:=fileInfo.FullName))
    Else 
        InvalidFiles.Add(fileInfo)
    End If
Next
```

Simple, fast and readable.

Comment: I am receiving a list of valid files back in a struct from a COM object and then I need to compare those to files in a directory and what I need is the difference between all the files and the files returned by the COM object