# Should I use a C# Dictionary if I only need fast lookup of keys, and values are irrelevant?

Tags: c#, dictionary, lookup

I am in need of a data type that is able to insert entries and then be able to quickly determine if an entry has already been inserted. A `Dictionary` seems to suit this need (see example). However, I have no use for the dictionary's `values`. Should I still use a dictionary or is there another better suited data type?

```
public class Foo
{
    private Dictionary<string, bool> Entities;

    ...

    public void AddEntity(string bar)
    {
        if (!Entities.ContainsKey(bar))
        {
            // bool value true here has no use and is just a placeholder
            Entities.Add(bar, true);
        }
    }

    public string[] GetEntities()
    {
        return Entities.Keys.ToArray();
    }

}
```

Comment: An interesting side note on the subject: Java's [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) is actually just a wrapper around `HashMap`. They do exactly what you suggest, but they put a prettier face on it. =)

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728500/hashsett-versus-dictionaryk-v-w-r-t-searching-time-to-find-if-an-item-exist statistical compare showing as a chart

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx).

> The `HashSet<T>` class provides high-performance set operations. A set
>   is a collection that contains **no duplicate elements, and whose
>   elements are in no particular order**.

Comment: Note that unlike dictionary there is no need to check for existance before adding.

Comment: @Evk - you don't need to check for existence before adding to a Dictionary either if you use the indexer.

Comment: Yes but in the event that the information is useful for other reasons, `HashSet<T>.Add()` returns a `bool` indicating if the item was successfully added (not there before)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Did not know that! Just managed to remove about 30 lines of code from our system as we'd written a helper method that did just that! Thanks

Comment: @MatthewSteeples in that case I feel I should mention that `HashSet<T>.Remove` works the same way. It returns a `bool`; `true` if the item was found and removed, `false` otherwise. No exception thrown, no need to call `Contains`.

Comment: @hoodaticus: Yes that's true but using the index to add items to a dictionary will overwrite existing items with the same key. Unless this is the desired way you'd like your code to run, it can lead to unexpected results when querying items therein.

Answer (score 3):

[Habib's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42584857/3063273) is excellent, but for multi-threaded environments if you use a `HashSet<T>` then by consequence you have to use `lock`s to protect access to it. I find myself more prone to creating deadlocks with `lock` statements. Also, `lock`s yield a worse speedup per [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law) because adding a `lock` statement reduces the percentage of your code that is actually parallel.

For those reasons, a [`ConcurrentDictionary<T,object>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) fits the bill in multi-threaded environments. If you end up using one, then wrap it like you did in your question. Just `new` up `object`s to toss in as values as needed, since the values won't be important. <s>You can verify that there are no `lock` statements in its [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs)</s>.

If you didn't need mutability of the collection then this would be moot. But your question implies that you do need it, since you have an `AddEntity` method.

**Additional info 2017-05-19** - actually, `ConcurrentDictionary` *does* use locks internally, although not `lock` statements *per se*--it uses `Monitor.Enter` (check out the [`TryAddInternal`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,bc495056297a0851) method). However, it seems to lock on individual buckets within the dictionary, which means there will be less contention than putting the entire thing in a `lock` statement.

So all in all, `ConcurrentDictionary` is often better for multithreaded environments.

It's actually quite difficult (impossible?) to make a concurrent hash set using only the [Interlocked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx) methods. I tried on my own and kept running into the problem of needing to alter two things at the same time--something that only locking can do in general. One workaround I found was to use singly-linked lists for the hash buckets and intentionally create cycles in a list when one thread needed to operate on a node without interference from other threads; this would cause other threads to get caught spinning around in the same spot until that thread was done with its node and undid the cycle. Sure, it technically didn't use locks, but it did not scale well.